# cannot find keystone_authtoken in ceilometer.conf while setting up

Tags: ubuntu, openstack

I am trying to set up ceilometer on my Ubuntu system taking the guide from this website:

[ceilometer setup on ubuntu from openstack](http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/content/)

Under the section [install telemetry](http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/content/ceilometer-install.html) in the 11th step they say change in

```
/etc/ceilometer/ceilometer.conf
```

file under the section

```
[keystone_authtoken]
```

But the problem is , in my file there is no such section. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Like other OpenStack services, Ceilometer expects configuration options in specific sections of the configuration file. You can update the existing file by inserting the section header manually. For example, adding both the section header and the configuration option for CA cert location would require you to add the following:

```
[keystone_authtoken]
cafile=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

For the Juno OpenStack release (circa 2014), the full list of options and section headers are listed at http://docs.openstack.org/juno/config-reference/content/section_ceilometer.conf.html.